# Jpgraph: Barplot growing from right to left

Tags: php, jpgraph

I'm trying to create two horizontal bar plots that are side by side. The one on the right will be using the the default Set90andMargin and will grow from left to right. The one the left, I would like to make grow from right to left since the vertical values will be similar as the other graph.

I've considered just using negative numbers but I still want to use label the graph on the axis though. Is there any way to use jpgraph so that it plots from the right side growing to the left hand direction?

Tried using Set90andMargin and then SetAngle to 270 (adding 180 degree to the rotation):
Image results are as follows:
enter image description here

[image: original left to right image]

[image: rotate right to left image]

Comment: I've tried using Set90andMargin then rotating by 180 degrees but that results in a graph size reduction (note that I do not say image size reduction). I am working on a 1600 by 500 aspect ratio graph but after the 180 rotation the graph becomes roughly 500 by 500 which gets centered in a 1600 by 500 image.

Comment: Did you add anything inside the brackets when using `->Set90AndMArgin()`? Because it's not rotating anything for me..